# JSF using same form for search and insert

Tags: jsf, lifecycle

I have a form on top of the web page having some field with validations.
So when i am doing add operation i would like to do field validation but when i am doing search operation i dont want to perform validation.

using immediate="true" will avoid validation check, but won't update values of the variables in the bean.

So how can i bypass process validation phase but still get values updated in model.

I am using JSF 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this hint of using JSF EL

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/action-dependent-requireness.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can't, immediate = true results in no update to the underlying model. You have a couple of options available to you :

1) Try using two separate form elements, one for the search and one for the add. Note that posting one back won't post the other one back.

2) Remove the automatic validations and do it manually on the postback.

Cheers,

Andy